# redirect connection to honeypot service

Tags: logging, honeypot

i am currently redirecting attackers to themselves based on a few rules

```
<iptables> -t nat -A PREROUTING -s <ip> -j DNAT --to-destination <ip>
```

i was thinking that maybe it could be of help to others if, instead of just looping back the packets, i redirected it to a public honeypot.

then, they could analyze the attacker's actions/behavior and add to their heuristics database or blacklist.

do you guys know of any service like that?

PS: i do not intend to add any third-party content (like scripts) to my domain, so the honeypot should accept redirected connections.
[Project Honey Pot](https://www.projecthoneypot.org/) looks nice, but they require fiddling with my web page.

Comment: You do realize that the redirected attacks will appear to have originated from you?

Comment: @korockinout13 won't `SNAT` on `POSTROUTING` solve this problem?

Comment: the way this normally works is that you run the honeypot and upload the logs to the central repo

Comment: @RASG that might be disallowed by some ISP routers since the source IP is invalid, but I don't know if things are actually configured that way in practice. Plus, TCP handshakes won't be able to complete, so the connections will never happen.